# Use PHP in Script to send data too Google Tag Manager

Tags: javascript, php, google-tag-manager

So right now I am doing something like what is below. What I want to be able to do is pass data dynamically to GTM.. I know I am doing it wrong but I need some help in figuring out how i need to go about this. Again. ALL I want to do is send some data in PHP variables to Google Tag Manager so I can view in GA.

Thank you!

```js
<script>
dataLayer.push({
   'transactionId': '<?php echo $order['id']; ?>',
   'transactionTotal': '<?php echo  number_format($order['subtotal'],2) ?>',
   'transactionProducts': [{
      'sku': '',
      'name': '<?php echo $order['programName']; ?>',
      'price': ,
      'quantity': 
   }],
   'event' : 'OrderComplete'
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, how do you know that you are doing it wrong? Are you getting syntax errors?

Comment: Yes, Getting syntax error and data is not passing to Google analytics

Comment: What's the syntax error? My PHP is rusty, but have you tried using double quotes, for example `'<?php echo $order["id"]; ?>'`. Also, the `sku`, `price`, and `quantity` are required pieces of information (https://support.google.com/tagmanager/answer/6107169?hl=en).

Comment: What if I do not have data for those categories?

Comment: I would be strange not to have them if you are selling products, but if you don't have them, then I guess an empty string would suffice to satisfy the dataLayer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you just missed the **'** on your json object.

```
dataLayer.push({
    'transactionId': '<?php echo $order['id']; ?>',
    'transactionTotal': '<?php echo  number_format($order['subtotal'],2) ?>',
    'transactionProducts': [{
        'sku': '',
        'name': '<?php echo $order['programName']; ?>',
        'price': 'here',
        'quantity': 'here'
        }],
    'event' : 'OrderComplete'
});
```

The rest is fine.

If you got no values for those field, let them be empty by writing an empty string **''**.

```
<?php
    function myProducts() {
        $result = array();
        foreach($products as $product) {
            array_push($result, "{
                'sku': '" . $product['sku'] . "',
                'name': '" . $product['name'] . "',
                'price': '" . $product['price'] . "',
                'quantity': '" . $product['quantity'] . "'
            }");
        };

        return implode(",", $result);
    }
?>

dataLayer.push({
    'transactionId': '<?php echo $order['id']; ?>',
    'transactionTotal': '<?php echo  number_format($order['subtotal'],2) ?>',
    'transactionProducts': [<?php echo myProducts()?>],
    'event' : 'OrderComplete'
});
```